# Using TikZ, how do I draw a box having an adjustable width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I want to box text using TikZ and adjust the box width such that the text is appropriately put on different lines within the box. I also want the text on each to be centered within the box. As this is my first experience using TikZ, I'm a bit lost as to what can and cannot be done. This is what I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\myboxwidth}
\newcommand{\MyBox}[3][XXX]{
\settowidth{\myboxwidth}{#1} % THIS DOESN'T WORK
%\setlength{\myboxwidth}{20mm} % THIS WORKS
\draw (#2) 
%\pgfextra{\setlength{\myboxwidth}{20mm}} % THIS WORKS
%\pgfextra{\settowidth{\myboxwidth}{#1}}  % THIS DOESN'T WORK
node 
[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em,
text width=\myboxwidth,
text centered, inner sep=1ex] {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\MyBox[animals]{0,0}{animals cats \& dogs}
\MyBox[trees]{3,0}{trees oak aspen}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the left-hand box, I want "animals" on the first line and "cats & dogs" on the next, while in the right-hand box every word must be on its own line. Why is it that specifying `\myboxwidth` with an explicit length like 20mm works but asking LaTeX, which is what I'm using, to evaluate the word length fails? Each of the lines followed by a `THIS WORKS` or `THIS DOESN'T WORK` comment have been tried one at a time.

In addition to the above, I've tried using `{\parbox{\myboxwidth}{#3}}` instead of just `{#3}` and I've also tried the obvious line-splitting with `\\` without success. Can anyone help please?

Oh, and placing the `\settowidth` command before `\begin{tikzpicture}` works too.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PGF math has a `width` function that measures the width of its parameter. It can be accessed with `\pgfmathparse{width("some text")}` or `\pgfmathwidth{"some text"}`. The result is then stored in `\pgfmathresult`.

I think `text centered` is a depreciated option. Using `align=center` instead makes `\\` work as expected.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\MyBox}[3][XXX]{
    \pgfmathwidth{"#1"}
    % store the result before it gets overwritten by some internal call to `\pgfmath...`.
    \let\myboxwidth\pgfmathresult
    \draw (#2) 
        node 
        [rectangle,draw,minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em,
        text width=\myboxwidth,
        text centered, inner sep=1ex] {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyBox[animals]{0,0}{animals cats \& dogs}
    \MyBox[trees]{3,0}{trees oak aspen}

    \draw (0,-2) node 
        [rectangle, draw, align=center, inner sep=1ex] {animals\\ cats \& dogs};
    \draw (3,-2) node 
        [rectangle, draw, align=center, inner sep=1ex] {trees\\ oak aspen};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Both of these solutions only work with TikZ/PGF version 2.10 (and higher).

Comment: This work just as I want it to. But why is it that `\pgfmathwidth` cannot be used directly but has to be passed on to `\myboxwidth`?

Comment: The `align=center` is even better as now I don't have to evaluate the text width. Brilliant.

Comment: @Luis: All the pgf-math macros don't return the value but set `\pgfmathresult` to the result of the combination. I guess this avoids some potential problems.

Comment: I noticed the explanatory question to my `\pgfmathwidth` comment only now.:-)

Answer (score 4):

Just a little change in Caramdir's solution. Use `text width=\widthof{#1}`. The results are the same.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\MyBox}[3][XXX]{
    \draw (#2) 
        node 
        [rectangle,draw,minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em,
        text width=\widthof{#1}, %<---- Change here
        text centered, inner sep=1ex] {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyBox[animals]{0,0}{animals cats \& dogs}
    \MyBox[trees]{3,0}{trees oak aspen}

    \draw (0,-2) node 
        [rectangle, draw, align=center, inner sep=1ex] {animals\\ cats \& dogs};
    \draw (3,-2) node 
        [rectangle, draw, align=center, inner sep=1ex] {trees\\ oak aspen};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful tip. I see that tikz/pgf is very powerful and flexible, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calc,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}b{\widthof{#1}}}
\newcommand\MyBox[2][XXX]{%
  \fbox{\tabular[b]{C{#1}} #2 \endtabular}}
\begin{document}

foo 
\MyBox[animals]{animals cats \& dogs}\quad
\MyBox[trees]{trees oak aspen} 
bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've done this as well using PSTricks, but I wanted to do this now specifically using tikz. You can do it also by saying `\settowidth{\myboxwidth}{some} \fbox{\parbox{\myboxwidth}{some text}}`.