# Tikz: Using \pgfmathwidth (or \widthof) with \Large text causes crash

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I;m trying to utilise this method for putting a box around text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20326/17049

But it doesn't work with large text...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathwidth{\Large "Text"}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Causes:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi
l.6     \pgfmathwidth{\Large "Text"}
```

Comment: From the PGF Manual: "It is important to remember that any expression is expanded with `\edef` before
being parsed, so any macros (e.g., font commands like `\tt` or `\Huge`) will need to be `\protected`" (e.g.,
`\noexpand\Huge` is usually sufficient)."

Comment: @KevinC With `\pgfmathwidth{"\noexpand\Large Text"}`, `\pgfmathresult` is set to 0pt. On the other hand, `\pgfmathwidth{\noexpand\Large "Text"}` gives errors.

Comment: @egreg: That's strange... I get the correct measures with your first syntax. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PGF Manual:

> It is important to remember that any expression is expanded with `\edef` before being parsed, so any macros (e.g., font commands like `\tt` or `\Huge`) will need to be "protected" (e.g., `\noexpand\Huge` is usually sufficient)."

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parskip{20pt}
\begin{document}
Width of text: \pgfmathwidth{"Text"}\pgfmathresult

Width of {\Large Text}: \pgfmathwidth{"\noexpand\Large Text"}\pgfmathresult

Width of {\Huge Text}: \pgfmathwidth{"\noexpand\Huge Text"}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Did you try it inside a `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: @egreg: You're right, `\pgfmathwidth{"\noexpand\Large Text"}` doesn't work inside a `tikzpicture` environment, except when issued in a `\node`. Could this be a bug? I'm still using PGF 2.10 though.

Comment: you need two more `\noexpand` to make it work. there must be a duplicate for this somewhere

Comment: @percusse: `\pgfmathwidth{"\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\Large Text"}` gives a result of `20.00003`, which is the same as `\pgfmathwidth{"Text"}`. But this is still incorrect `:(`